# How to add Newton's constant to the metric function?

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, black-holes, metric-tensor, physical-constants

My main question is, is it possible to manually add Newton's constant $G$ to the metric function of a black hole? Is there such a possibility for Black Brane? How to add? Should it be added to the main parameters of the black hole? That is, to parameters such as mass and charge...

Comment: $G$ is already in the Schwarzschild metric.  Most practicing physicists use units where $G = 1$, but if you want to see it in SI units look at [the version on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric)

Comment: Use dimensional analysis to determine where factors of $G$ and $c$ and $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ should be.

Answer (score 2):

The [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) (for a black hole with mass $M$)
already contains the gravitational constant $G$,
when spelling out the Schwarzschild radius $r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$:
$$\begin{align}
ds^2 &= \left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)c^2dt^2 \\
 &-\left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)^{-1}dr^2 \\
 &-r^2d\theta^2-r^2\sin^2\theta\ d\phi^2
\end{align}$$

And in a similar way the [Reissner-Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric)
(for a black hole with mass $M$ and charge $Q$)
already contains the gravitational constant $G$
and the electric constant $\epsilon_0$:
$$\begin{align}
ds^2 &= \left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}+\frac{GQ^2} {4\pi\epsilon_0c^4r^2}\right)c^2dt^2 \\
 &-\left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}+\frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^4r^2}\right)^{-1}dr^2 \\
 &-r^2d\theta^2-r^2\sin^2\theta\ d\phi^2
\end{align}$$

For a [black brane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_brane) you can do it in the same way
by spelling out the Schwarzschild radius $r_s$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and detailed explanations. I tried to apply such a process to equation (14) from (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.09242.pdf), but I encountered some problems. Do you think this equation has a dimensional problem? How can we add this parameter without causing dimensional problems?

Comment: @Saber This article seems to use so-called natural units all over the place,
i.e. $G=1$ and $c=1$. For example in equation (5)
$G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$,
which actually is meant to be
$G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu\nu}$.
So you need to add the missing factors of $G$ and $c$ in many places to make them dimensionally consistent.

Comment: With respect to the above arXiv, we have parameters with dimensions as follows, 
$$[r] = L$$
$$[m] = L^{-1}$$
$$[e] = [C] = 1$$
$$[b] = L$$
$$[c_0] = L$$
$$[c_1] = [c_2] = [c_3] = 1$$
The $[G]$ for this 5d black brane has, 
$$[G] = L^3$$ 
So we need to add one term such as $G^{2/3}$ in the third term to solve the dimension problem with added Newton constant 
is this true? I didn't see in the other papers such as $G^{2/3}$ in the metric function